# SortBy Spring Data MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have passed my query from postgres to mongodb, everything is correct. But in the ordering I do not see how to integrate it within @Query as in the example sql

// sql-postgres ( repository )

```
@Query("select c from ClienteElser c where c.securityDomainId IN (2,10) and c.deleted is null order by c.razonSocial")
```

//mongodb ( repository )

```
@Query("{security_domain_id: { $in: [2,10] },'deleted':null}")
public List<Cliente> findAllByOrderByRazonSocialAsc(Sort sort);
```

//service

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "razon_social");
    List<Cliente> result = clienteRepository.findAllByOrderByRazonSocialAsc(sort);
```

At the moment I have fixed it like that, but I would prefer it to be inside @Query

And order giving priority to capital letters, I do not know how to avoid that. Example : "ACS" is before "Abalos"

Can someone help me to integrate the sort within @Query with mongodb and that does not differ between uppercase and lowercase

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been adressed in [DATAMONGO-1979](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1979) for the Lovelace release (aka Spring Data MongoDB 2.1.0).

It will allow to set a default sort for repository query methods via the `@Query` annotation.

```java
@Query(sort = "{ age : -1 }")
List<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname);
```

Using an explicit `Sort` parameter along with the annotated one allows to alter the defaults set via the annotation. The method argument `Sort` parameters will be added to / or override the annotated defaults depending on the fields used.

```java
@Query(sort = "{ age : -1 }")
List<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname, Sort sort);
```